# @requestmapping params="form"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

Could someone explain the `params="form"` parameter in requestmapping?
For example like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I understand the `{id}` is being passed in as a number and and the GET is self explanatory, but the `params = "form"` puzzles me. I'm obviously new to Spring MVC, and I can't find an explanation. If anyone knows of a good tutorial covering this subject I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ensures that the URL has the query parameter 'form'.

So that RequestMapping would match an url like this: `some_url/123?form` but not `some_url/123`